# Why LUT works wrong?

Tags: unity-game-engine, lookup-tables, post-processing

I have trouble that even neutral LUT change view not properly (totally green even black places). For example: [[View without LUT]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8AKR.png) [[View with neutral LUT]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7fmx.png) [[Neutral LUT]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQAEZ.png).
I tried to change color space, and [image import settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIMb5.png). But without result.

How can I fix wrong color changing with Lookup Textures?

I am using Unity 2020.1.0a17.2089 and Post Processing v 2.2.2 (From package manager)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already got help from Unity forum (https://forum.unity.com/threads/why-lut-works-wrong.1061534/#post-6858545)

If you get some problem flip LUT vertically.
[Correct neutral LUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13VVY.png)